# Threeparttable centering

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, threeparttable

I know that someone already asked pretty much the same but I cannot solve the problem of centering my table after using `threepartatble` command for the notes.

Here it is:

```
\begin{table}[h!tb] 
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\caption{Table1}
\label{one}
\begin{tabular}{l r r r} 
\toprule
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{country} & region & county & village \\
North Africa & 13.0 & 11.0 & 7.0 \\
Central and South Africa & 2.0 & 5.0 & 7.3 \\
Middle East & 5.3 & 3.0 & 3.0 \\
Asia & 19.0 & 24.0 & 16.7 \\ 
Southern Europe & 10.6 & 4.0 & 3.0 \\
ACP countries & 43.6 & 43.0 & 46.0 \\
Unallocated & 6.5 & 10.0 & 17.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item Source: book
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). And for inline code you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863).

Comment: I get perfect centering with your input. Note that `\hline` is inappropriate and the `\multirow` is wrong. Add `\midrule` after the header row.

Answer (score 1):

Please compare this two tables if they are different in their alignment. If that is the case, please check if your packages are all up to date. If they are, we have to compare versions. For this, add `\listfiles` to the preamble and get the package versions from the `main.log` file.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\listfiles % prints the versions of all used packages to the .log file

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{table}[h!tb] 
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\caption{Table1}
\label{tab:one}
\begin{tabular}{l r r r} 
\toprule
 country & region & county & village \\
\midrule
North Africa\tnote{1} & 13.0 & 11.0 & 7.0 \\
Central and South Africa & 2.0 & 5.0 & 7.3 \\
Middle East & 5.3 & 3.0 & 3.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item [1] Source: book
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
%
\begin{table}[h!tb] 
\centering
\caption{Table2}
\label{tab:two}
\begin{tabular}{l r r r} 
\toprule
 country & region & county & village \\
\midrule
North Africa & 13.0 & 11.0 & 7.0 \\
Central and South Africa & 2.0 & 5.0 & 7.3 \\
Middle East & 5.3 & 3.0 & 3.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I mean is that, if not using threeparttable the table is perfectly horizontally align (centered) in the paper. when introducing the threeparttable the table (and consequently also the note) moves to the left of the paper

Comment: I edited my example two a direct comparison of a "normal" and a threepart table. Please check your package updates if they look different.

Comment: the problem still persist.

Comment: it is as if \centering is not working with threeparttable. Please help. I should hand in the paper :(

Comment: Sorry, as egreg also wrote, it does work fine as it is. Please update everything. Check `listfiles` to have `threeparttable` in Version from 2010 (I am having 2003 and it works, too). Be sure, just to load my example with `pdfLaTeX` without anything else. If you put my code in your paper, I am not able to know about any redfinitions and so on.